# OnHover over the div, <a> tag is not going on to the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically,

I have a scenario which is not working. Let me explain.

I have a div, onhover of which another div comes and the previous div goes into the background. Now what happens here is,

The div which comes after hover consist of a button. And on button there is link which redirects to another page. Also on that div. I have a `<a>` tag which also has a link but on click of that it does not works.

It works when I remove the button, but I want button also.

Please see the code for your reference:-
 Do let me know if you need anything else

```html
<div class="product-image-wrapper hidden-cls">
  <div class="single-products">
    <div class="productinfo">
      <img src="images/shop/product12.png" alt="" />
      <div class="padding-left">
        <h5>Koryo KLE32ELBH 
                    <br/>LED TV
                </h5>
        <p class="para-sky">Only 2 units left</p>
        <p>Koryo</p>
        <div class="arrow_box_blue">Best Seller</div>
        <br/>
        <p class="parag">
          <del>&#2352;</del>&nbsp;&nbsp;13,999
        </p>
        <h2>
                    <del>&#2352;</del>&nbsp;&nbsp;42,680
                </h2>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="deposit">Add to Compare

        </label>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="pdp.html">
      <div class="product-overlay">
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <!--   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">Qick Info</a> -->
          <a href="#" data-featherlight="#fl12" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">Quick Info</a>
          <div class="lightbox" id="fl12">
            <div class="top-header"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="product-details">
                  <!--product-details-->
                  <div class="arrow_box_red0 seller">Best Seller</div>
                  <div class="view-product" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <div class="thumb-image">
                      <img src="images/product-details/img-thumb-big1.png" data-imagezoom="true">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <h4 class="zoom-img">Mouse over image to zoom in</h4>
                  <div id="similar-product" class="carousel slide top-bottom-border" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="item active">
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil1.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil2.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil3.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil4.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil1.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil2.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil3.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil4.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil1.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil2.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil3.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                          <img src="images/product-details/thumbnil4.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left item-control" href="#similar-product" data-slide="prev">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right item-control" href="#similar-product" data-slide="next">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--/product-details-->
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
                  <h3>Samsung 32 H40000</h3>
                  <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                      <tr class="cart_menu">
                        <td colspan="4" class="image blue">
                          <span> SKU ID:</span> 000000006000013898
                        </td>
                        <td class="total text-right pull-right"></td>
                        <td width="220" class="total text-right">
                          <div>
                            <p class="pull-right">Add to Wishlist
                              <span> ♥
                                                                                                                        <span></span>
                              </span>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cfccca;">
                        <td colspan="4" class="tab-ProF">
                          <h5 class="key-features">Key Features</h5>
                          <ul class="key-features">
                            <li>32 Inches</li>
                            <li>USB support-Multi- Format Play</li>
                            <li>2 x HDMI</li>
                          </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="product-share-app text-right top">
                          <div class="btn-group top share-app">
                            <div class="rating">
                              <img src="images/star.png">
                              <span>Rating</span>
                              <div class="reviews">Reviews (045)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <h1 class="pull-left">Share this on</h1>
                              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked pull-right icon social-icon">
                                <li>
                                  <div class="social-icons">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                      <li>
                                        <a class="t" href="#">
                                          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                        </a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                        <a class="f" href="#">
                                          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                        </a>
                                      </li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 padding0">
                  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-4-ty-col padding0">
                    <div class="pro_description">
                      <p class="parag">
                        <del>र</del>&nbsp;&nbsp;24,990
                      </p>
                      <h2>
                                                                                                            <del>र</del>&nbsp;&nbsp;23,990
                                                                                                        </h2>
                      <p class="taxes">Inclusive of all taxes</p>
                      <p class="offers-txt">Special Offers: Extra 10:% Off</p>
                      <br>
                      <div class="add-to-chart-btn">
                        <input class="btn btn-default update" type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="chart">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-8-pdp" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                    <div class="cart_quantity_button qtn">
                      <a class="cart_quantity_up" href=""> + </a>
                      <p class="pra">Qty :&nbsp;</p>
                      <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                      <a class="cart_quantity_down" href=""> - </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" padding0 mrg-top10">
                  <div class="pull-left mrg-top10">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="deposit">Add to Compare

                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pull-left mrg-top10">
                    <ul class="lst-pro">
                      <li>
                        <a href="">View Full Product</a>
                      </li>
                      <span>|</span>
                      <li>
                        <a href="">Shipping Details</a>
                      </li>
                      <span>|</span>
                      <li>
                        <a href="">Specs</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="deposit">Add to Compare

          </label>
          <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also see the direct link for your reference:-

[Demo link](http://dev.genuusdemo.com/bigbazaar/plp.html)

Step to check:-

1. Hover on the first section under **LED's & LCD's** what will happen here is another div will come.There is a button with name *Quick Info* which has a link, it goes to the respective page. But other than that when I click, I have also given a link on `<a>` tag. which is not working.

I want that to work. Please help

Comment: None of the links on the Quick Info popup or on the product page do anything. They're all `<input />` with no `onClick` or form to submit them.

Comment: The Quick Info links work fine for me in Chrome, FF and IE11

Comment: Hovering on LED's & LCD's, for me, doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

How about playing around with the z-index property on the tags concerned? The order in which they are stacked might be preventing the `<a>` from working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because you have an `onclick` on the "product-overlay" `div`. What you need to do is, when the user clicks on the `label` tag, stop the propagation of the event so it doesn't execute the product-overlay's onclick.

In order to do that, just add a `event.stopPropagation();` at the beginning/end of the event that handles the `label` click event.

If you want to see how it would work in a quick way without changing any code:

1. Go to your [demo link](http://dev.genuusdemo.com/bigbazaar/plp.html).
2. Open the JavaScript console.
3. Execute the following code:

   `$(".overlay-content label").on("click", function() { event.stopPropagation(); });`
4. Now you can click on the "Add to compare" `label` without being redirected anywhere.

(Notice that the checkbox won't be checked as you stop the propagation of the event, you need to add the `stopPropagation` call wherever you were handling the `label`'s click)